# Find Relation 1 to n using cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

entity1 -> entity2 -> entity3 -> entity4 -> entity5

starting entity is entity1 
I want to get one of them below response till relationship from starting entity to connected entity.

It could be :-

```
 1) entity1
 2) entity1 -> entity2
 3) entity1 -> entity2 -> entity3
 4) entity1 -> entity2 -> entity3 -> entity4
 5) entity1 -> entity2 -> entity3 -> entity4 -> entity5
```

I tried like,
all connected from entity3.

```
  MATCH (n1:entity1)-[:Relationentitys]->(n2:entity2)-
  [:Relationentitys]->(n3:entity3)-[:Relationentitys]->(n4:entity4)-
  [:Relationentitys]->(n5:entity5) where n3.id='5084712c801f' AND n3.tag='entity3' RETURN n1,n2,n3,n4,n5
```

Relation entity are connected to each other in hierarchy.

I can not figure out that how to get using cypher.

Comment: Is this always going to be a chain of up to 5 entities, instead of a tree, with relationships branching into other nodes outside of the entities you want?

Comment: Yes, it is a chain of entities.

Answer (score 0):

If the nodes always form these simple chains, from 1 to 5 entities, without branching off into other nodes, then you can probably use a simple variable-length relationship match to get all the entity nodes in the chain:

```
// from the given entity, track back to entity1, the start of the chain
MATCH (n3:entity3)<-[:Relationentitys*0..4]-(en1:entity1)
WHERE n3.id='5084712c801f' AND n3.tag='entity3' 
// now get the full chain from entity1
MATCH (en1)-[:Relationentitys*0..4]->(en)
RETURN COLLECT(en) as entities
```

This should give you a collection of entities in the chain, up to however many exist in the chain.

Comment: Thanks for response.

Comment: Sure. I'm still not entirely clear on your needs here. The above should work no matter which entity you match upon. And if order doesn't matter so much, there are ways to improve this.

Comment: Yes, I want to know more about this, I am still not able to get according to my response.

Comment: Then please update your question with more details about what you want here, and also provide some details as to why this isn't working for you.